# Java 6 - Mapping java.sql.Types to Java types

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, types

I'm looking for a link to a table with the mappings between SQL types (java.sql.Types) to Java types.

Do you know where I can find one ?

Comment: **Update:** As of Java 8 and JDBC 4.2, the `java.sql.Types` class is supplanted by a proper [Java enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), [`JDBCType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/JDBCType.html), implementing the [`SQLType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLType.html) interface. Same idea, same values, but with the type-safety and convenience of enums.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *JDBC 4.x Specification*, provided by [JSR 221](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), provides this info in appendix B titled *Data Type Conversion Tables*.

See tables containing mappings from Java object types to JDBC types. Different tables exist for the mappings that will be performed when different methods of the JDBC API are invoked; for instance, a separate mapping exists for `CallableStatement.getObject` and `ResultSet.getObject` while another exists for the mappings used during `ResultSet.getXXX` methods.

Click through that [JSR 221](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) page to download a [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) of the spec document, currently JDBC 4.3.

Comment: You can download the spec from that page. Choose the final release.

Answer (score 4):

here is a document for Java 6. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#996857

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Have a look at [this article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#996857).

It may be better to look for documentation provided by the driver itself, as this will be more definite.

Comment: It's for the JavaSE 1.3. I'm looking for the JavaSE 6 version of this document.

Comment: As I said it comes down to the driver's implementation - oracle is just giving the guidelines. What driver are you using?

Comment: I use the JDBC driver of Postgresql.

Comment: updated the link for SE 6 (JDBC API 3) Postgresql JDBC unfortunately doesn't seem to have a concrete document on this.

Comment: I think this answers the question if you don't mind accepting, however you might ask specifically about how postgresql driver maps arrays if that's your issue.

Comment: The anwser is correct. But some types are unclear for me :  Types.DATALINK, Types.DISTINCT, Types.JAVA_OBJECT, Types.NULL and Types.OTHER.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the Derby database
[Sql Types](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefjdbc20377.html)