# Passing an array of Object from Java to PL/SQL function

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a Java array (java.sql.Array) object using an array of objects. I need to pass this Java Array to PLSQL stored procedure.

```
conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
JournalBean[] journal = listJournal.toArray(new JournalBean[listJournal.size()]); 
final Array sqlArray =   conn.createArrayOf("CHMCR.PACK_CHM_CR.FICHIER_CR_TYPE", journal);
cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call CHMCR.PACK_CHM_CR.CHARGEMENT_CR(?,?,?,?,?)}");
cstmt.setArray(1,sqlArray);
cstmt.setString(2, fileName);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(5, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

cstmt.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
```

however when I try to create this Array using the method (connection.createArrayOf), I am getting the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fonction non prise en charge
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createArrayOf(PhysicalConnection.java:9283)
```

this is my JournalBean is:

```
public class JournalBean implements  Serializable, SQLData {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2199201954799483472L;

    private int idCr;
    private int idChargement;
    private String numAutorisation;
    private String version;

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return "FICHIER_CR_TYPE";
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        idCr = stream.readInt();
        ...

    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {

        stream.writeInt(idCr);
        ...
    }
}
```

this is my new DDL (creating the type in database using CREATE TYPE):

```
create or replace TYPE            CR_TYPE AS OBJECT
( ID_CR NUMBER  ,               
ID_CHARGEMENT   NUMBER ,
NUM_AUTORISATION    VARCHAR2(24 BYTE),
VERSION NUMBER 
) ;
```

then creating the table type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FICHIER_CR_TYPE 
AS VARRAY(1000) OF CR_TYPE;
```

the procedure has became:

```
create or replace PACKAGE             PACK_CHM_CR
IS
   PROCEDURE CHARGEMENT_CR(
                                                              P_FICHIER_CR                       IN OUT FICHIER_CR_TYPE,
                                                              p_nom_fichier                        IN        VARCHAR2,                                         
                                                              p_id_chargement                       OUT NUMBER,
                                                              NMES                                        OUT NUMBER,
                                                              LMES                                        OUT VARCHAR2);
END PACK_CHM_CR;
```

I'm using Oracle 11g, java 6 and I had tried ojdbc14 and ojdbc6.

Comment: _Fonction non prise en charge_ in English is _Unsupported feature_

Comment: Does your `JournalBean` class inherit from `java.sql.SQLData`? If so, you can probably adapt your query to pass custom type using [something like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344166/java-how-to-call-an-oracle-procedure-with-custom-types/54347047#54347047).

Comment: Note that `FICHIER_CR_TYPE` must be a database type, i.e. you must use [CREATE TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375) statement. Creating a type in PL/SQL code will not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the [DDL] statement you used to create your database type.

Comment: In the DDL you posted, `fichier_CR_TYPE` is **not** a database type because it is defined **inside** a PL/SQL package. You posted the DDL that creates a PL/SQL package. Did you look at the Oracle documentation for the `CREATE TYPE` statement? The link to it is in my first comment.

Comment: @Abra i have changed the DDL code to CREATE_TYPE (see edited question) but still not working

Comment: What is your `JournalBean` class?

Comment: @MT0 i posted JournalBean

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation of createArrayOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]))

```
Array createArrayOf(String typeName, Object[] elements) throws SQLException
```

> If the resulting JDBC type is not the appropriate type for the given
>   typeName then it is implementation defined whether an SQLException is
>   thrown or the driver supports the resulting conversion.

Your typeName CHMCR.PACK_CHM_CR.FICHIER_CR_TYPE is custom. Try to use defined type and check if exception will disapear.

Please, find additional details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958778/java-6-mapping-java-sql-types-to-java-types).

Answer (score 0):

> ```sql
> create or replace PACKAGE             PACK_CHM_CR
> IS
>    TYPE fichier_CR_TYPE IS TABLE OF CHMCR.JOURNAL_OPERATION_CHANGE%ROWTYPE index by binary_integer;
> ```

You can't for three reasons:

1. `TYPE x IS TABLE OF y INDEX BY z` is an associative array. This is solely a PL/SQL data type and JDBC does not support passing associative arrays, only collections or VARRAYs (both non-associative array) data types (unlike in C# which only support associative arrays and not collections/VARRAYs).
2. It is defined in a `PACKAGE` which is a PL/SQL scope. If you want to pass a type it needs to be defined in an SQL scope using a `CREATE TYPE` statement.
3. The JDBC driver doesn't know how to convert from your `JournalBean` class to a `fichier_CR_TYPE` database type. You either need to pass to a simple array (there are built-in types that can be used like `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST`) or you need to tell Java how to map between the class and the database type ([SQLData is one method of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344166/java-how-to-call-an-oracle-procedure-with-custom-types/54347047#54347047)).

You need to fix all 3 of these issues.

---

**Update**:

The `JournalBean` class does not map to `FICHIER_CR_TYPE` as that is an array; they type should be of the object type `CR_TYPE`:

```java
public class JournalBean implements  Serializable, SQLData {
  // ...
  public static final String SQL_TYPE = "CR_TYPE";

  @Override
  public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
    return SQL_TYPE;
  }
}
```

You also need to register the type with the connection:

```java
conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

Map<String,Class<?>> typeMap = conn.getTypeMap();
typeMap.put( JournalBean.SQL_TYPE, JournalBean.class );
```