# Retrieving data from associative array of custom object type from Oracle DB using CallableStatement

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, plsql, ojdbc

## Summary

I am calling a **stored procedure(SP)** in an **Oracle 12c** database from a Spring-boot application. I am using **CallableStatement** to do this. One of the OUT parameters of the SP is an **associative array** with elements of a custom object type. I am having trouble retrieving the data in a proper method.

### Code

```
TYPE trans_list IS TABLE OF T_RPT_TXN_DTLS_OBJ INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
TYPE T_RPT_TXN_DTLS_OBJ AS OBJECT( id VARCHAR2(20), amount NUMBER(10,2), desc VARCHAR2(100))

Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
OracleCallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call SAMPLE_PROC(?,?)}").unwrap(OracleCallableStatement.class);
callableStatement.setString(1, ID); 

--Here I don't know what to do--
callableStatement.registerIndexTableOutParameter(2, 500, OracleTypes.OTHER, 0);
--------------------------------
```

### Things I have tried

I looked through different websites using google. Went through stackoverflow as well. The above code is where I am stuck at. Since the 3rd argument is the datatype of the array elements, I put in `OracleTypes.OTHER` but that throws an `SQLException: invalid column type 1111`.
I read in the official docs that for custom object types, we can map them to Java objects. I have no idea how to do that either. Please refer to *User_defined types* in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/datacc.htm#BHCGCBJC

### What I am asking in brief

Any sample code, detailed docmentation, links to online examples that fits my case. I specifically need to know arg[2] of the out parameter registration, and how I might go about mapping to a custom Java object from the `callableStatement` (perhaps using `.getObject(int)` but I don't know about the mapping).

Comment: have you tried? oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes#ARRAY (2003)

Comment: @RaviSamani yes, I did. it raises "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid PL/SQL Index Table element type".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58027920/1509264).

You cannot.

1. You need to define the data type in the SQL scope (using `CREATE TYPE`) rather than in the PL/SQL scope, in a package as JDBC can only work with SQL defined data types.
2. A consequence of point 1 is that JDBC does not support associative arrays, as they are a PL/SQL only data type, and you need to use collections (unlike C#, which only supports associative arrays and does not support collections). So you need to remove the `INDEX BY` clause from the type.
3. You need to be able to map from the type in the array to a Java data structure; one way of doing this is to use the `SQLData` interface. An example is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347047/1509264).

Answer (score 0):

Define:

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"trans_list");
```

Call proc:

```
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Then get out parameter as

```
   java.sql.Array array = callableStatement.getArray(2);
   Object outputParamValue = array.getArray();
```

Type Caste outputParamValue if needed.

Comment: I have tried this. I keep getting the error "java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Image is not in 8.1 format"