How to process tabular data from Oracle PL/SQL function in JAVA?
What I am used to is working with ResultSets from PreparedStatements, e.g.
try (PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlQueryString)) {
    try (ResultSet queryResult = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (queryResult.next()) {
            // do something with queryResult
        }
    }
}

Now, I created a PL/SQL function in an Oracle DB returning a table of data:
create or replace FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION 
(
  IN_PARAMETERS...
)
RETURN OUT_TABLE_TYPE IS
    RESULT_ROWS OUT_TABLE_TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT <fields>
    BULK COLLECT INTO RESULT_ROWS
    FROM SOME_TABLE
    WHERE <some complicated filter>

    RETURN RESULT_ROWS;
END MY_FUNCTION;

I would like to call this function in JAVA and iterate over the rows of data returned from the function. This is how far I am:
String dbCall = "{? = call MY_FUNCTION(?, ...)}

try (CallableStatement functionCall = dbConnection.prepareCall(dbCall)) {
            
    functionCall.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "SOME_TABLE");
    // register input parameter values:
    functionCall.setInt(2, value1);
    functionCall.set... // more input

    functionCall.executeUpdate();

    // now what??? I tried something like this:
    Array test = functionCall.getArray(1);
    while (test.getResultSet().next()) {
        // test contains data, but I don't know how to process it.
    }    
}

How do I iterate over the data row by row?

Use a cursor, don't use a collection.

If you really want to use a collection then look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/66912178/1509264

Write the function as:
CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION 
(
  IN_PARAMETERS...
)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  v_result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_result FOR
    SELECT <fields>
    FROM SOME_TABLE
    WHERE <some complicated filter>;

    RETURN v_result;
END MY_FUNCTION;

Then loop through the result set in exactly the same way as you would from a procedure.

MTO's answer solved my problem. However, I needed to change my JAVA code quite a bit to process the cursor returned from the database function. Hence, here the updated Java code for documentation. PL/SQL was implemented according to MTO's answer:
String callStatement = "{? =  call %sMY_FUNCTION(?, ...)}";

try (Connection connection = _dbConnector.getDbConnection()) {
    try (OracleCallableStatement functionCall = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall(callStatement)) {

        functionCall.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        functionCall.setInt(2, value);
            ... more parameters

        // Note that I call EXECUTE here
        functionCall.execute();

        try (ResultSet queryResult = functionCall.getCursor(1)) {
            while (queryResult.next()) {
                // process queryResult ...
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

This works now. Thanks MTO.

To answer the original question "How do I iterate over the data row by row?":
The columns of the result set you extract from the Array are pairs of objects: the first is an integer, the index of the row (1 based), the second is an Object implementing the Struct interface.
You get the actual columns of the SQL OBJECT behind the table by calling the getAttributes() function returning an Object[] containing the expected values in the order of the fields declaration of the original SQL OBJECT.
Array test = functionCall.getArray(1);
ResultSet rs = test.getResultSet();
while (rs.next()) {
    Struct s =  (Struct) rs.getObject(2);
    Object[] o = s.getAttributes();
...
}

Note that numbers are returned as BigDecimal.
